# JavaScript (document.write) does not function in a frameset

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset, document.write

I have an HTML frameset page (don't judge), where I have used some JavaScript (`document.write`) to display the tag of a frame with a variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
        <script src="script.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <frameset cols="70%,30%" frameborder="0">
        <frame src="site1.html" />
        <script>
            document.write('<frame src="site2.html?var=' + variable + '" />');
        </script>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

So I can't get this to work. The problem is that, now that I've used JavaScript to `document.write` the tag for a frame, the frame does not show. How is there a way to successfully incorporate this JavaScript in my frameset?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm gonna be *that* guy. Why are you using frames and documentwrite? Both of them are waaaay out of date.

Comment: `var frame = document.createElement('frame'); frame.src = "'site2.html?var=' + variable; document.getElementById('frameId').appendChild(frame);` Might work. Completely untested.

Comment: The above comment should not be construed that I think this is a good idea.

Comment: @jdphenix I agree. OP should really consider using modern techniques, regardless of the so far absent reason as to why they are using code from the nineties. Two immediate things come to mind, (1) future proofing, and, (2) for their own learning - it would not be productive to learn & spend time on framesets and documentwrite.

Comment: Frameset documents don't really permit contents of their own, including `<script>`s, outside of `<noframes>` elements. Perhaps, look at using [`<iframe>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in a standard `<html>` document instead. You can use [CSS `position`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to achieve the same placement as with the `<frameset>`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You're right. I don't mean that I disagree with the other reactions; I would have said the same if I was answering. I regretfully wanted to use an old-fashioned `frameset` to fulfill my needs, but another more modern solution is available: yours. I guess I've learned that `frameset`s suck even more!